# How to find different in days between 2 datetime object as date?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have a datetime field in my MySQL database. I am using Laravel and Carbon library is already included. I am building a function to compare this datetime field with current date. Currently, when using diffInDays function in Carbon, here will be the result:

```
Datetime field      | current time         | result
2016-09-13 23:59:59 | 2016-09-14 16:42:12  | 0
2016-09-13 12:05:59 | 2016-09-14 16:42:12  | 1
2016-09-12 23:59:59 | 2016-09-14 16:42:12  | 1
2016-09-12 12:05:59 | 2016-09-14 16:42:12  | 2
```

However, I want to compare the date only, so I want the result to be:

```
Datetime field      | current time         | result
2016-09-13 23:59:59 | 2016-09-14 16:42:12  | 1
2016-09-13 12:59:59 | 2016-09-14 16:42:12  | 1
2016-09-12 23:59:59 | 2016-09-14 16:42:12  | 2
2016-09-12 12:05:59 | 2016-09-14 16:42:12  | 2
```

Is there already a pre-built function in PHP / Carbon / other libraries for this?

Comment: DateTime has the [diff() method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php);

Comment: And the DateInterval type that it returns has a `days` property.

Comment: Carbon extends DateTime and therefore like mark says, you can use the `diff()` method

Comment: Read the question. Using the method you suggest will result in what I don't want as mentioned above.

Comment: Set time on each operand to 00:00:00? *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this, is to use DateTimeImmutable, set the time to midnight (for example) on both, and then do the diff. This will net you the result you want.

```
$start = new DateTimeImmutable ("20160101T1530", $dtz);
$stop = new DateTimeImmutable ("20160102T1300", $dtz);

// DateTimeImmutable returns new objects when modified.
$chkStart = $start->modify ("midnight");
$chkStop = $stop->modify ("midnight");

// Setting second flag to "true" to get absolute difference.
$diff = $chkStart->diff ($chkStop, true);
```

Comment: Instead of cloning you can use [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/datetimeimmutable) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'd totally missed that class somehow. Updated my answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
$checkDate = "2016-09-13 23:59:59";
$convertData = Carbon::parse($checkDate)->format('Y-m-d');
$createdObject = new Carbon($convertData);
$now = Carbon::now();    
$difference = $now->diffInDays($createdObject);
dd($difference);
```

Comment: Rather than just posting code and urging the OP to 'try it', it is generally better to provide some explanation of your code and why it is better than the OP's attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If carbon diff() is not working for you, you can try alternative method..

In your controller write..

```
$date1       = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-09-12 13:02:24');
$anotherDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date1)->format('Y-m-d');

$diff = $this->time_elapsed_string(strtotime($anotherDate));
return $diff;     // 2
```

create a method in your controller..

```
private function time_elapsed_string($ptime)
{
    $etime = time() - $ptime;
    if ($etime < 1)
        return '0 seconds';

    $a = array( 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'day');

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
    {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1) {
            $r = floor($d);
            return intval($r);
        }
    }
}
```

It will give you difference in days..